# Kotlin completion with multiple parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, completionhandler

Imagine a method with a multiple parameter completion:

```
fun foo(completion : (p1 : Int, p2 : Int) -> Unit){
    completion(1, 2)
}
```

How to access p1 and p2 when calling `foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `foo` with a simple lambda like this:

```
foo { p1, p2 -> 
    //do stuff
}
```